# Is there a faster way of creating and iterating over a 200x200 grid in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, grid

I am new into Javascript and for the purposes of a simple game, I need to display a 200x200 grid on a page, with each cell containing a boolean value. My current approach looks like this: I create an HTML table dynamically, assign IDs and add a checkbox on each cell.

Here is how I go about creating my table:

```
    const a = 200;
    var resultTable = '<table name = "mytab" id = "abc">';
    for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        resultTable += '<tr>';
        for (var j = 0; j < a; j++) {
            var uid = i + '.' + j;
            resultTable += '<td class="container"><input type="checkbox" id="' 
            + uid + '" class="regular-checkbox"><\/td>';
        }
    }
```

and this is how I am collecting values:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < a; j++) {
                var yy = i + '.' + j;
               /* if (document.getElementById(yy).checked) do something */
            }
    }
```

It works but there are some serious performance issues. Is there a different approach of doing this faster? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you iterating over the entire grid when a checkbox's is being checked or unchecked?

Comment: First, the user "draws" a pattern with the checkboxes and then I perform an animation using that pattern. Every "frame" essentially, is a full iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A performance enhancement would be selecting the elements. Currently you create the entire table from a string and later select each input with `document.getElementById()`. You could improve this by creating a reference to each input when you create the elements, so you don't have to find it later on.

With [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) you can create instances of elements in JavaScript. The function returns a reference to the created element which you can store to use later on.

For example, you could create an input element with it.

```
const input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'checkbox';
input.checked = true;
```

Now you have an input element already saved in the `input` constant. Now you don't have the find the element later on as you already have a reference to it, making the loop having to do 1 less task per input, resulting in **200 x 200 less tasks**.

The example below uses the aforementioned `createElement` method to create a `<table>` element. In the second loop the `<input>` element is created and a reference to the element is stored in an array. Looping through this array is now **n(0)** which allows you to loop through each input in a single loop.

```
const amount = 200;
const inputCollection = [];

const table = document.createElement('table');
table.name = 'mytab';
table.id = 'abc';

for (let i = 0; i < amount.length; i++) {
  const row = table.insertRow();

  for (let j = 0; j < amount.length; j++) {
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.classList.add('regular-checkbox');
    input.type = 'checkbox';

    // Add the input reference to the collection.
    inputCollection.push(input);

    const cell = row.insertCell();
    cell.append(input);
  }
}

document.body.append(table);

inputCollection.forEach(input => {
  if (input.checked) {
    // Do something.
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this has been very helpful! There has been an improvement, but here are still performance issues. Performance is flawless when I am changing the table dimentions to say 50x50. Maybe creating 40000 table cells was not a good idea in the first place...

Comment: Having that many elements and animating them all at once will always be heavy on the browser. However, you've shared little about the rest of your application, for example how the animations are performed. Though this question specifically was about the second loop. If it helped out, please mark the answer as accepted. If you need further feedback on performance improvements, then create a new post at [codereview.stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and include a working snippet with a minimal version of your game. They might be able to help you out even more.